# Is the cat (Jones) in Alien immortal?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Just watched [Alien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28film%29) for [the first time](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3951838#3951838). I've got two related questions about Jones, the cat:

- Is it in stasis at the start? I didn't see it with anyone waking up.
- How did it survive the ending, when

> Ripley depressureised the shuttle cabin and sent the alien into space?

Comment: The cat is a Time Lord!

Comment: @Xantec: what, of the robotic time travelling type?

Comment: she put the cat into a space-cat-carrier that was pressurized before she got into the shuttle.

Comment: *"No wonder she and the cat had survived the Nostromo. Curiosity and a talent for survival were two of the skills they’d shared. **Jonesy was gone now, a victim of the time distortions made necessary by space travel.** No more cat-nightmares for him. Only she was left to deal with life, and all the memories."* - Alien³ novelisation.

Comment: I read this just now and thought: *who asked **this** crazy question?!* Oh, that's right...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ripley put Jones into a hyper-sleep chamber inside the shuttle before noticing that the Alien was aboard.  Jones rode out the depressurization in there.

[image: Ripley putting Jones into the sleep chamber]

Ripley putting him into the foot of the chamber is a good indicator of where he was at the beginning of the movie, down at the foot of one of the sleep chambers where we couldn't see him.  He appears at the meal table just after the group awakening when everyone is socializing and eating.